# Concatenate columns in alphabetical (or numerical order)

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose a df:

```
      col1      col2
1        A         B
2        A         C
3        G         A
```

I want to get:

```
      col1      col2     col3
1        A         B       AB
2        A         C       AC
3        G         A       AG
```

Is there any short function to achieve that? or I need to write my own and apply?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use list comprehension with sorting by [`numpy.sort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html) or `sorted` and `join`:

```
df['col3'] = [''.join(x) for x in np.sort(df)]

#alternative
#df['col3'] = [''.join(sorted(x)) for x in df]
print (df)
  col1 col2 col3
1    A    B   AB
2    A    C   AC
3    G    A   AG
```

With lambda function is obviously solution slowier:

```
df['col3'] = df.apply(lambda x: ''.join(sorted(x)), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can sort values with [`numpy.sort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html) and concatenate with [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
df['col3'] = list(map(''.join, np.sort(df)))
```

Output:

```
  col1 col2 col3
1    A    B   AB
2    A    C   AC
3    A    G   AG
```